# Notepad++ Regex: Insert a new line with text 'found' after last occurance of the word '$apple'

Tags: notepad++

Full question :

Insert a new line with text `found` after last occurance of the word `$apple`.
If not found, try the same for the word `$orange` in the same file.

Ex: File `abc.txt`

```
$apple
$orange
```

after running the regex :

```
$apple
found
$orange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\$apple)(?!.*\$apple)|((?:(?!\$apple).)*?)(\$orange)(?!.*(?:\$orange|\$apple))`
- Replace with: `(?1$1\nfound:(?3$2$3\nfound))`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  (\$apple)                     # group 1, literally $apple
  (?!.*\$apple)                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't $apple after
|                           # OR
  ((?:(?!\$apple).)*?)          # group 2, everything that is not $apple
  (\$orange)                    # group 3, literally $orange
  (?!.*(?:\$orange|\$apple))    # make sure we haven' $orange or $apple after
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1                 # if group 1 exists (we have found $apple)
    $1                  # content group 1
    \n                  # linefeed, you may use \r\n for wondows EOL
    found               # literally found
  :                 # else
    (?3                 # if group 3 exists ($orange)
        $2                  # content of group 2
        $3                  # content of group 3
        \n                  # linefeed, you may use \r\n for wondows EOL
        found               # literally found
    )                   # endif
)                   # endif
```

---

### With $apple AND $orange

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

---

### with $orange ONLY

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode with dot all enabled:

```
Find:    (\$apple(?!.*\$apple)|\$orange(?!.*\$orange))
Replace: found
```

### Demo

To understand how the above regex alternation works, consider the first half which covers searching for `$apple`:

```
\$apple(?!.*\$apple)
```

This will match `$apple`, but only if another occurrence cannot be found in the text (i.e. it is the last occurrence).  The logic for matching the last `$orange` is identical, but note that a search for `$orange` would only fire if `$apple` cannot be found anywhere.